# While Loop Subtracting one month from a date to a given day

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

Am trying to subtract one month from a date backwards to a given date. The code i have written does the subtraction but i don't know why it doesn't complete the loop. below is the code block

```
$date7 = date('Y-m-10');
$lastsaving = date("2013-2-9"); 


while($lastsaving < $date7){

$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( $date7 ) ) ;
$date7 = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );


echo $date7; 
echo "<br />";
}
```

result i get is

```
2015-05-10 
2015-04-10 
2015-03-10 
2015-02-10 
2015-01-10 
2014-12-10 
2014-11-10 
2014-10-10 
2014-09-10 
2014-08-10 
2014-07-10 
2014-06-10 
2014-05-10 
2014-04-10 
2014-03-10 
2014-02-10 
2014-01-10 
2013-12-10
```

please help me find the reason it's not completing the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
 $lastsaving = date("2013-2-9");
```

to

```
 $lastsaving = date("2013-02-9");
```

Here, you can see the working one : 
http://codepad.org/uI0R6TvC

The guy above me is right as well :)
that would work too

```
while(strtotime($lastsaving) < strtotime($date7)) {
```

tested here : http://codepad.org/OY36ij3U

Comment: https://eval.in/375401 - will not work in case if `$lastsaving = date("2015-5-10");`. If the year is same and the month is different it will not enter the loop.

Comment: No.. it will not work because of the issues of comparing. It will try to convert them.

Comment: ofcourse this is why i asked him to add the month as 05 ... http://codepad.org/0x3CrSGm

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo that $lastsaving = date("2013-02-09"); worked thanks alot this wasted my two days am glad its working

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert them to **timestamp** first for comparing.Use `strtotime()` for this -

```
while(strtotime($lastsaving) < strtotime($date7)) { ... // rest of the code
```

Comment: i think it should go upto 2013-02-10

Comment: It will not matter if you use `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0):

i changed `$lastsaving = date("2013-2-9");` to `$lastsaving = date("2013-02-09");` as suggested by @Danyal Sandeelo above